# problems reading a csv by column in python

Tags: python

I have a CSV file that has white space i.e. blank rows or random new lines as in the example below

```
header1,data1
header2,data2

header4,data4

header6,data6
```

The following example below works fine when the CSV has no white space, but is there a way to load a CSV by column with white space?

```
import csv

file = csv.reader(open('file.csv'))
blob = zip(*file)
```

Comment: What is the error it is producing?

Comment: @bludger the blob will come up as `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd filter the rows before the `zip` [python 2 assumed for the `open`]:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open("blank.csv", "rb") as fp:
...     reader = csv.reader(fp)
...     rows = [line for line in reader if line]
...     blob = zip(*rows)
...     
>>> blob
[('header1', 'header2', 'header4', 'header6'), ('data1', 'data2', 'data4', 'data6')]
```

`if line` here is basically equivalent to `if len(line) > 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas will work:

```
import pandas
pandas.read_csv("tmp.txt", header=None)

         0      1
0  header1  data1
1  header2  data2
2      NaN    NaN
3  header4  data4
4      NaN    NaN
5  header6  data6
```

you probably want to filter out the NaNs.

Comment: pandas is very nice but is there a pure python way todo it?